# WebConnector with Auto-Run checked, inserting Duplicate Invoice to the QuickBooks with Rails 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, quickbooks, autorun, duplicates

I am using web connector to add invoice to the QuickBooks v13. I have also added your provided logic to add invoice if the invoice is not already added to the QuickBooks.

When I have set the AutoRun option of the web connector so that it will automatically call the API. If I have only one invoice to add, for the first run it is working fine. But for the second call by the webconnector, search result for the invoice in the QuickBooks sends the record with statusCode="0" that means it is already exist but still it once again added the same invoice to the QuickBooks. I am not able to restrict the adding of same invoice multiple time

Following are the Rails code to insert invoice to the QuickBooks. I am using qbwc gem in my Rails application to send QBXML request and parse the response

```
def api

  if request.get?

    render :nothing => true

    return

  end

  if params["Envelope"]["Body"].keys.first =="authenticate"

    add_invoice #add invoice method will be called to search/add invoice

  end

  req = request

  Rails.logger.info "=== #{ params["Envelope"]["Body"].keys.first}  ==="

  res = QBWC::SoapWrapper.route_request(req)

  Rails.logger.info render :xml => res, :content_type => 'text/xml'

end
```

#Action to Search/Add invoice

```
def add_invoice

  #searching the invoice from QuickBooks

  QBWC.add_job('search_invoice') do

   '<QBXML>

      <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">

        <InvoiceQueryRq requestID="1">

          <RefNumber>58869</RefNumber>

        </InvoiceQueryRq>

      </QBXMLMsgsRq>

    </QBXML>'

  end



  #response of the search result

  QBWC.jobs['search_invoice'].set_response_proc do |r|

    if r["xml_attributes"]["statusCode"] == "500" || r["xml_attributes"]["statusCode"] == "1"

      #Add the invoice

      QBWC.add_job('add_invoice') do

        '<QBXML>

       <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">

       <InvoiceAddRq requestID="58869">

       <InvoiceAdd>

       <CustomerRef>

       <ListID>8000000D-1365397507</ListID>

       <FullName>john.doe@test.com</FullName>

       </CustomerRef>

       <TxnDate>2013-04-08</TxnDate>

       <RefNumber>58869</RefNumber>

       <BillAddress>

         <Addr1>N Dallas Parkway</Addr1>

         <City>Addison</City>

         <State>TX</State>

         <PostalCode>75001</PostalCode>

         <Country>United States</Country>

       </BillAddress>    

           <ShipAddress>

         <Addr1>N Dallas Parkway</Addr1>

         <City>Addison</City>

         <State>TX</State>

         <PostalCode>75001</PostalCode>

         <Country>United States</Country>

       </ShipAddress>

         <IsPending>true</IsPending>

         <PONumber>Test QB</PONumber>

         <TermsRef>

                  <FullName>VISA</FullName>

                </TermsRef>

         <ShipDate>2013-04-15</ShipDate>

         <InvoiceLineAdd>

         <ItemRef>

         <FullName>test Invoice</FullName>

         </ItemRef>

         <Desc>test Description</Desc>

         <Quantity>1</Quantity>

         <Rate>1000</Rate>

         </InvoiceLineAdd>

       </InvoiceAdd>

       </InvoiceAddRq>

       </QBXMLMsgsRq>

        </QBXML>'

      end

    end

  end  

end
```

I have set the AutoRun option of the web connector to 5 min, so that it will automatically run with 5 minute interval and call the API.

Let's say the invoice with RefNumber#58869 is new and not present in the QuickBooks.

When the WebConnector call the API, QBXML request to search the invoice with RefNumber#58869 will be sent to the QuickBooks. It gives the following response

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n<QBXML>\n<QBXMLMsgsRs>\n<InvoiceQueryRs requestID=\"1\" statusCode=\"500\" statusSeverity=\"Warn\" statusMessage=\"The query request has not been fully completed. There was a required element ("58869" that could not be found in QuickBooks.\" />\n</QBXMLMsgsRs>\n</QBXML>\n"
```

and then invoice is added successfully to the QuickBooks

When the webconnector will call api after 5 min interval, QBXML request to search the invoice with RefNumber#58869 will be sent to the QuickBooks. It gives the following response

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n<QBXML>\n<QBXMLMsgsRs>\n<InvoiceQueryRs requestID=\"1\" statusCode=\"0\" statusSeverity=\"Info\" statusMessage=\"Status OK\">\n<InvoiceRet>\n<TxnID>15F-1365397789</TxnID>\n<TimeCreated>2013-04-08T10:39:49+05:30</TimeCreated>\n<TimeModified>2013-04-08T10:39:49+05:30</TimeModified>\n<EditSequence>1365397789</EditSequence>\n<TxnNumber>62</TxnNumber>\n<CustomerRef>\n<ListID>8000000D-1365397507</ListID>\n<FullName>john.doe@test.com</FullName>\n</CustomerRef>\n<ARAccountRef>\n<ListID>8000001E-1364292331</ListID>\n<FullName>John Doe</FullName>\n</ARAccountRef>\n<TemplateRef>\n<ListID>80000001-1364291996</ListID>\n<FullName>Intuit Product Invoice</FullName>\n</TemplateRef>\n<TxnDate>2013-04-08</TxnDate>\n<RefNumber>58869</RefNumber>\n<BillAddress>\n<Addr1>16001 N Dallas Parkway</Addr1>\n<City>Addison</City>\n<State>TX</State>\n<PostalCode>75001</PostalCode>\n<Country>USA</Country>\n</BillAddress>\n<BillAddressBlock>\n<Addr1>16001 N Dallas Parkway</Addr1>\n<Addr2>Addison, TX 75001</Addr2>\n<Addr3>United States</Addr3>\n</BillAddressBlock>\n<ShipAddress>\n<Addr1>16001 N Dallas Parkway</Addr1>\n<City>Addison</City>\n<State>TX</State>\n<PostalCode>75001</PostalCode>\n<Country>USA</Country>\n</ShipAddress>\n<ShipAddressBlock>\n<Addr1>16001 N Dallas Parkway</Addr1>\n<Addr2>Addison, TX 75001</Addr2>\n<Addr3>United States</Addr3>\n</ShipAddressBlock>\n<IsPending>true</IsPending>\n<IsFinanceCharge>false</IsFinanceCharge>\n<PONumber>United Way</PONumber>\n<TermsRef>\n<ListID>8000000C-1364361757</ListID>\n<FullName>Visa</FullName>\n</TermsRef>\n<DueDate>2013-04-08</DueDate>\n<ShipDate>2013-04-15</ShipDate>\n<Subtotal>67.24</Subtotal>\n<ItemSalesTaxRef>\n<ListID>80000012-1364967363</ListID>\n<FullName>Sales Tax</FullName>\n</ItemSalesTaxRef>\n<SalesTaxPercentage>0.00</SalesTaxPercentage>\n<SalesTaxTotal>0.00</SalesTaxTotal>\n<AppliedAmount>0.00</AppliedAmount>\n<BalanceRemaining>67.24</BalanceRemaining>\n<IsPaid>false</IsPaid>\n<IsToBePrinted>true</IsToBePrinted>\n<IsToBeEmailed>false</IsToBeEmailed>\n<CustomerSalesTaxCodeRef>\n<ListID>80000001-1364291997</ListID>\n<FullName>Tax</FullName>\n</CustomerSalesTaxCodeRef>\n</InvoiceQueryRs>\n</QBXMLMsgsRs>\n</QBXML>\n
```

Here 'statusCode' is "0" means response says that the invoice is already present in the QuickBooks.

But still the same invoice again added to the QuickBooks. And I am not able to find any solution to restrict the adding of same invoice multiple time.

I have tracked the "statusCode" and found that QuickBooks is sending the correct status code. I am also maintaining a flag in the order table to track the invoice already added for the order to the QuickBooks or not. I think my problem is with WebConnector. When WebConnector's AutoRun option is active, it is adding the last order's invoice again and again if there is no order left to add to the QuickBooks.

Comment: Post the rest of your code. The Web Connector *only does what you tell it to* so you must have some logic error in your code. Unless you post the rest of your code, there's no way for anyone to help you.

Comment: No issue with the webconnector. I have fixed the issue by deleting the data from the session, if the data is already added to the QuickBooks with the help of the qbwc gem.